# How to fix "502 Bad Gateway" on Ubuntu Nginx Flask web server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, http-status-code-504

**ENVIRONMENT:**

ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Python 3.7.9

**PROBLEM:**

When I open a specific page on my Flask web app, I get this error message:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

**WHAT I DID :**

I check the logs:

**/www/wwwlogs/access.log**

```
152.32.150.7 - - [07/Sep/2023:05:56:59 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
152.32.150.7 - - [07/Sep/2023:05:56:59 +0000] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
185.161.248.31 - - [07/Sep/2023:08:30:43 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-"
205.210.31.228 - - [07/Sep/2023:11:08:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com"
104.140.148.82 - - [07/Sep/2023:11:19:54 +0000] "GET /UEPs HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
45.227.254.49 - - [07/Sep/2023:12:03:24 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-"
185.11.61.122 - - [07/Sep/2023:13:21:38 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-"
171.67.70.84 - - [07/Sep/2023:15:34:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
185.11.61.122 - - [07/Sep/2023:23:53:42 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-"
45.227.254.49 - - [08/Sep/2023:12:30:39 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-"
198.235.24.123 - - [08/Sep/2023:12:57:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com"
167.94.138.124 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:25:14 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03\xDAZ\xC0\xA4'\xBEa\xCA\x809\x87\x1Bt@\xB1I\xF1\x0E\x0F\xA3\xF2\xEDn+\xF4\x93w)\xBD\x15\xD6A \xA0BT\xA0\xCFSwgs\xAA\xE7%\x1EW\x9F\x80\x97\xC8\xE5$\xBA\xE5\xE4\xBD\xB9\xC9h\xFBWm7'\x00&\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-"
167.94.138.124 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:25:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "-"
167.94.138.124 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:25:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
167.94.138.124 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:25:16 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 150 "-" "-"
167.248.133.187 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:51:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
167.248.133.187 - - [08/Sep/2023:14:51:41 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 150 "-" "-"
170.130.204.50 - - [08/Sep/2023:17:01:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A515F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36"
170.130.204.50 - - [08/Sep/2023:17:01:42 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03\xADNl\x96U" 400 150 "-" "-"
170.130.204.50 - - [08/Sep/2023:17:01:42 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA0\x01\x00\x00\x9C\x03\x03\x1E@a2\x99+\xB2\xADh<\xDBO\xDB'N\xBE\xEA\x08\x85ld\xBD\xC9\x85\xBC5\x93\x0C\xEF\x19` \x00\x00*\xC0+\xC0/\x00\x9E\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xCC\xAA\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-"
171.67.71.80 - - [08/Sep/2023:17:30:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
185.156.72.7 - - [08/Sep/2023:20:00:28 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00,'\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Domain" 400 150 "-" "-"
185.156.72.7 - - [08/Sep/2023:20:00:28 +0000] "\x03\x00\x00,'\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Domain" 400 150 "-" "-"
198.235.24.68 - - [08/Sep/2023:20:45:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com"
167.94.145.57 - - [09/Sep/2023:05:07:53 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03\xB2\xDC\xE2lN\x82\x89W\xB6\x93(\xCF{qA\x9C?.\xCE\xD3\x06\x9C\x9B\xBB\xDB\x1A\xE3\xA0>\x84=' /\xA3\x8B\xEA\xDB^l\xACU\x9EN\xC5\xAFv,\xE9eIa\xE2\xD6\x80Si\xA3}\xA8X\x09\xE41@\x00&\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-"
167.94.145.57 - - [09/Sep/2023:05:07:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "-"
167.94.145.57 - - [09/Sep/2023:05:07:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
167.94.145.57 - - [09/Sep/2023:05:07:54 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 150 "-" "-"
171.67.70.84 - - [09/Sep/2023:08:30:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
167.248.133.35 - - [09/Sep/2023:11:17:37 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03\xD6\x03P\x1A)\xC3b\xBF\x0Fo>B\xAE\xFD\xA7p~\xAD`\x1E\xDB\xCA\xB7\x09\x10\xC7]\x1B8\xE0Z\xCA  %\xD3\xC8[\x8F\x03\xC6\xCE4\x1E\xB0NP4d1\x92\x92\xF3A\x09\xDE\x0Fy?\xF1V\xAFdZ\x86\x00&\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-"
167.248.133.35 - - [09/Sep/2023:11:17:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "-"
167.248.133.35 - - [09/Sep/2023:11:17:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
167.248.133.35 - - [09/Sep/2023:11:17:38 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 150 "-" "-"
```

The flask error logs don't show anything wrong in the code.

So I followed the recommendations found on the web by raising the time in config files:

**/www/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf**

```
user  www www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log  /www/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid        /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 51200;
        multi_accept on;
    }

http
    {
        include       mime.types;
                #include luawaf.conf;

                include proxy.conf;

        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
        client_header_buffer_size 32k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        sendfile   on;
        tcp_nopush on;

        keepalive_timeout 600;


        tcp_nodelay on;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 100000;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 100000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 100000;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1k;
        gzip_buffers     4 16k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
                limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;

        server_tokens off;
        access_log off;



server
    {
        listen 888;
        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
            location ~ /tmp/ {
                return 403;
            }

        #error_page   404   /404.html;
        include enable-php.conf;

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
        {
            expires      30d;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
        {
            expires      12h;
        }

        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }

        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/access.log;
    }
include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

**/www/server/nginx/conf/proxy.conf**

```
proxy_temp_path /www/server/nginx/proxy_temp_dir;
proxy_cache_path /www/server/nginx/proxy_cache_dir levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_one:20m inactive=1d max_size=5g;
client_body_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffers 4 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 128k;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_404;
proxy_cache cache_one;
```

Then I restarted nginx. But I still have this issue.

Where else should I look for? Anyone has a solution please?